# Несколько тернарных операторов в выражении

Tags: python

```
x = (1 if True else 2
     + 3 if True else 4
     + 5 if False else 6)
print(x)
```

Выводит `1`. Можно ли подобным синтаксисом получить `10` без нескольких statement-ов?

Comment: Тернарный оператор правоассоциативный (группируется справа налево), и низкоприоритетный (как, например, у умножения приоритет выше чем у сложения, так и у сложения выше чем у тернарного), поэтому ваше выражение группируется так `1 if True else ((2 + 3) if True else ((4 + 5) if False else 6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Нужно расставить скобки:

```
x = ((1 if True else 2)
     + (3 if True else 4)
     + (5 if False else 6))
```